# CloudWatch integration with MarkLogic DHS

Tags: marklogic

Does DHS (AWS version) provide native integration with CloudWatch?
Expecting resource monitoring, log monitoring and also billing alert usage.

Answer (score 0):

No, we dont provide the native integration today. This is on our roadmap.

I'd like to know more about your usecase here. Are you open to take a short meeting to discuss more details about your usecase?